# Change Firefox to latest nightly Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: ubuntu, firefox, ubuntu-10.04

I like the features and functionality of the new Nightly firefox builds (4.0) but I don't want to install it beside my firefox installation on Ubuntu which is the default and only browser on the system.

Is there any way that I can just replace the files from the stock firefox 3.6 to the nightly 4.0?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the [Mozilla Daily](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-mozilla-daily/+archive/ppa) PPA to your sources, update, and install the following packages:

```
firefox-4.0
firefox-4.0-core
firefox-4.0-branding
firefox-4.0-gnome-support
```

Remove the analogous installed non-4.0 firefox packages. It will show up as *Minefield 4.0 Web Browser* in your applications menu.

Comment: Thanks, I actually did find out about this method just a little while ago, thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that you want to copy your firefox 3.6 profile to firefox 4 (i.e. keep all your settings, bookmarks, addons,etc.)?

If that is what you want to do this should help: Video of how to [backup](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8lEEnsFcUHg) and [restore](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OAIKajlslnE) your profiles in Ubuntu. (In short use the FEBE addon/extension in FF, if that doesn't work just copy your profile folder and paste it from the same place in the newer version you copied it from)

Comment: No I don't really care about the profiles, the actual binary firefox files, I want them replaced with the new latest ones, from the nightly trunk. I can download the nightly build but would a simple overwrite on the default firefox ones work?